# How to move selected row in Horizontal Table View to leftside

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios5, ios7

I have transformed UITableview as in the attached screenshot:
[image]

and I am using the below code to move the table:

```
[mTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

Only the first 2 cells are getting adjusted to left side:
[image]
Now according to my requirement "C" should occupy "B"'s position, but it is not moving because all the cells are visible:
[image]
How can I acheieve this?

Comment: Please provide second screen

Comment: unable to add pictures .. trying to add

Comment: Add a link and someone will tag it. Does it work as you expect if you remove  "transformation" ?

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi Incuded all the pics now

Comment: @A-Live I didn't verify it .. but I can not remove transformation o the table because as per our requirement we need Horizontal table view only

Comment: Does the moved item should be deleted from the row?

Comment: No I didn't delete it. It is just moving. And I have fixed the issue by adding an empty cell at the end.

Comment: @Dee you know that you can disable pieces of code and re-enable them after tested the results, right ? Narrowing the problem is the key to solve it quickly and your table setup might be invalid by itself, the transformation might have nothing at all to do with it. For example: you didn't show us the number of items at the table.